# What is the meaning of "p = (int[2]){*p};" line in C pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, compound-literals

From what I understood, I am passing the address of the variable `a` to the function `int ffx1`.

After that, what exactly does this line `p = (int[2]){*p};` mean?

```
int ffx1(int * p)
{
    p = (int[2]){*p};
    return(p[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    a = ffx1(&a);
    printf("%d", a);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(int[2]){*p}` is compound literal. `p = (int[2]){*p};` such as `int array[2] = { *p, 0 }; p = array;`

Comment: if it is a compound literal populating the array, it's not specifying a value for the 2nd element of the array, which is the one that is returned which could be UB

Comment: @AndyG Yes it is, see BLUEPIXY's comment.

Comment: @coderredoc Lifetime

Comment: @coderredoc Although: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.5 Compound literals 5 The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the
initializer list. If the compound literal occurs outside the body of a function, the object
has static storage duration; otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with
the enclosing block.*

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.:If possible  Write this out,,,this is good to discuss?

Comment: @EOF Why is Lifetime a problem?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It isn't. I was speculating about why somebody would think this was UB

Comment: @EOF ah, by the way I do not think this is UB.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a **pointer to compound literals**.

**C11-§6.5.2.5 Compound literals (p9):**

> EXAMPLE 2 In contrast, in
>
> ```
> void f(void)
> {
> int *p;
> /*...*/
> p = (int [2]){*p};
> /*...*/
> }
> ```
>
> p is assigned the address of the first element of an array of two
>   ints, the first having the value previously pointed to by p and the
>   second, zero. The expressions in this compound literal need not be
>   constant. The unnamed object has automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 12):

With `int ffx1(int * p)`, `p` is a pointer to an `int`.

`(int[2]){*p}` is a *compound literal* defining an `int` array of 2. [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041388/could-someone-please-explain-this-code/47041662#comment81029741_47041388) This unnamed array we will call `X[2]`. Its first element have the value of `*p`, and the next element, being an `int` will be initialized to zero (§6.7.9 21 & 10 ) as it is not explicitly listed.

`p = ....` assigned the pointer `p` to a new value.  In this case, the above array `X[]`is converted to the address of its first enrollment or `&X[0]`.

`return p[1]` de-references `p`, returning the value in `X[1]` or `0`.

Comment: Thanks. your answer is right.. But since it is mentioned p[1] and int[2] then what is the length of the unnamed array? 2 or 3?

Comment: @hago The unnamed array, called `X[]` in this answer, consists of 2 elements because of the `(int[2])`.

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation. but here instead of writing p = (int[2]){*p}; can I write int *q = (int[2]){*p}; then what should be my return statement?
return p[1] or q[1]? I guess q[1] right

Comment: @hago Yes you can write  `int *q = (int[2]){*p}` to avoid changing the local variable `p`.  `return q[1]` would work like above.  `return p[1]` would work with the original `p` passed in which does not pointer to 2 elements.

Comment: Why did you mention "all zero bit pattern" ? It happens to be true in this case, since `int` is defined as having all zero bit pattern for zero value; but if let's say it were an array of pointers, then the other entry gets the null pointer -- not necessarily all zero.  The other entries are initialized as if by `{0}`

Comment: @M.M "Why did you mention "all zero bit pattern" --> Because I recalled it as that the memory will be filled with all zero bits as in `calloc()`.  Yet non-explicit initialization in general is as you say - potentially not an all zero bit pattern - answer amended.